# VBA in Excel Run Time Error 13: Type Mismatch

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to open a file dialog box in excel so a user can select a file. For some reason I keep getting a run time error after I've selected the file I want. Here is the code:

```
Dim dartFile As String

dartFile = Application.GetOpenFilename _
(Title:="Please choose DART output to open", _
FileFilter:="Excel Files *.xlsx* (*.xlsx*),")

If dartFile = False Then
    MsgBox "No file selected.", vbExclamation, "Sorry!"
    Exit Sub
Else
    'Run the rest of the Sub
End IF
```

The error pops up when ever I select a valid .xlsx file, and the debugger says there is something wrong with this line:

```
If dartFile = False Then
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `Dim dartFile As Variant` (so it can host a bool or a string)

Comment: Doh! Sneaky variant data type.. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Avoid using `Variant` data types, whenever possible.

> ```
> Dim dartFile As String
> ```

That's a good declaration, `dartFile` *is*, after all, a `String`.

This returns `True` in the immediate pane, when you <kbd>ESC</kbd> out of the dialog:

```
?Application.GetOpenFilename() = "False"
```

Just make `False`, `"False"`, and you're done. ;)

Comment: Thanks for that explanation @retailcoder, I figured it was a String, just couldn't figure out what the problem was.

Comment: @JonathanGeorge thanks for the checkmark! You may be interested in [codereview.se], a Stack Exchange site where you can post your working code and have it peer reviewed & improved in many ways. Cheers!

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that `Application.GetOpenFilename` returns a variant and you've declared your variable as a string.  VBA then can't compare your string with a boolean type.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
Dim dartFile As as Variant
```